# How to find the category Id in the wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am new to wordpress , I need to know how to find the category id instead of category name ?
in the wordpress .

Any one Much appreciated

Reg,
vicky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
     $category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
     $q = 'cat=' . $category_id;
     query_posts($q);
     if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

     the_content();

     endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Taken from the Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID

Comment: Much appreciated. I look forward to learning from you folks.

Once again Thanks,....

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
global $wp_query;
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
```

Comment: Thanks, For Your Quick Reply. Is this code to find the category id for the specified category name  ??